# Problem when assigning a keybinding to open the output of a shell command in vim

Tags: key-bindings, command-line, split

I wanted to have the output of a(any) shell command to open up in a vim split.
Did a bit of research and found out that the command to do so was:

```
:new | 0read | ! ls                       ---  (or something of this form)
```

But the issue I am facing is that when I try to bind it to something like this :

```
nmap ,s :new | 0read | !            --- (without a specific command at the end)
```

*Also tried with a specific command at the end and same result*

it is showing up this **error everytime I open up vim**:

```
line  277:
E32: No file name
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

---

**Edit** : It was not exactly an issue with binding, the command had a small issue.

Use this command:

```
nmap ,s :new | 0read !
```

---

---

**Btw the accepted answer has a function implementation which is much better than this simple mapping**

Comment: Have you tried replacing `|` with `<bar>`?

Comment: That, or escape the pipe character, otherwise Vim believes you want to have 3 commands on a single line - try `\|`

Comment: The second pipe between `0read` and the bang should also be removed.

Comment: @user9433424 that was the issue, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To open the output of a command in a new window:

```
:new +0r!ls
```

Note the syntax of [`new`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Anew):

```
:[N]new [++opt] [+cmd]                                  :new
```

And for [`+cmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%2Bcmd):

```
                                                        +cmd [+cmd]
The [+cmd] argument can be used to position the cursor in the newly opened
file, or execute any other command:
        +               Start at the last line.
        +{num}          Start at line {num}.
        +/{pat}         Start at first line containing {pat}.
        +{command}      Execute {command} after opening the new file.
                        {command} is any Ex command.
To include a white space in the {pat} or {command}, precede it with a
backslash.  Double the number of backslashes. 
        :edit  +/The\ book           file
        :edit  +/dir\ dirname\\      file
        :edit  +set\ dir=c:\\\\temp  file
Note that in the last example the number of backslashes is halved twice: Once
for the "+cmd" argument and once for the ":set" command.
```

So, to run a command in a new window, you can just `+` with `:new`, the command being `0r!ls`. This can quickly become a pain with complex commands, though.

In an map, leaving the command to you to enter:

```
nnoremap ,s :new +0r!
```

You could also write a function to read in the command:

```vim
function! SplitRunCommand()
    call inputsave()
    let l:cmd = input('Command: ')
    new
    call append(0, systemlist(l:cmd))
    call inputrestore()
endfunction

nnoremap ,s :call SplitRunCommand()<cr>
```

Now, when you type `,s` you'll be prompted:

```
Command:
```

Then, say:

```
Command: date '+%y%m%d'
```

And you will have a new window with the output of `date '+%y%m%d'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and especially for the function. Btw I have set the buffers to ask whether to save or not on close by default. How to change this behaviour for this specific split?

Comment: @meain In your temporary split, you could set the local-buffer value of the `buftype` option to `nofile`. It could give something like: `nnoremap ,s :new \| setlocal buftype=nofile \| 0r!` Or you could add `setlocal buftype=nofile` inside the `SplitRunCommand()` function, just after the `new` command.

Comment: @meain in addition to what user9433424 says, also see [`:h special-buffers`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#special-buffers) (in particular the scratch buffer)